# Operations with cuDoubleComplex inside cuda-kernel

Tags: c++, cuda, complex-numbers, cublas

I have a question to my implementation of a cuda kernel.

I generated a cude kernel where i want to add elements of cuDoubleComplex Variables. Later on i also want to do some multiplication on elements.

I tried several ways but could not find a solution.

My function is:

```
 __global__ void process(double *fieldRange, double *fieldAzimut, double **recPosition, double **transPosition, double *TimeAxisPulse, double timeStep, cuDoubleComplex *rawData, int nmbrPulses, int nmbrSamples, double carrierFrequency, cuDoubleComplex *result)
```

where I try to do something like

```
result[tid]=result[tid]+newValue
```

where newValue is also a cuDoubleComplex.  I tried to use the cublasZaxpy function, but I am told it is not allowed to call a host-function from a global function

What can i do to do a simple addition inside a kernel with cuDoubleComplex Variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call the function `cuCadd`, for example:

```
result[tid]=cuCadd(result[tid],newValue);
```

And also make sure you have `#include "cuComplex.h"` or `#include <cuComplex.h>` whichever works according to your path setup.

Comment: ok, thats very nice! I was not aware of this functions. 
cuCmul is the function for multiplication if anyone else is interested...

Comment: @raspiede for more reference for `cuComplex.h` and its functions you can take a look at [this](http://graphics.im.ntu.edu.tw/~bossliaw/nvCuda_doxygen/html/cu_complex_8h.html) and for the actual header file itself (which I find easier to understand) you can take a look at [this one](http://pixel.ecn.purdue.edu:8080/purpl/WSJ/projects/DirectionalStippling/include/cuComplex.h)